# Redshift connection occasionally drops

Tags: java, spring-boot, jdbc, amazon-redshift, aws-java-sdk

I am connecting to redshift cluster using redshift jdbc driver but the connection drops after sometime.I have tcpKeepAlive set to 1 minute but that didn't help either.

Here is the exception i get:

```
      java.sql.SQLException: [Amazon](500150) Error setting/closing 
      connection: Not Connected.
```

Here is the connection bean:

```
       @Bean(name="redShiftConn")
      public Connection connRedShift() {
         Connection conn = null;
       try{
         Class.forName("com.amazon.redshift.jdbc42.Driver");
        //Open a connection and define properties.
         System.out.println("Connecting to database...");
         Properties props = new Properties();
         props.setProperty("user", user);
         props.setProperty("password", password);
         props.setProperty("tcpKeepAlive", "true");
         props.setProperty("TCPKeepAliveMinutes", "1");
         props.setProperty("ssl", "true");
         props.setProperty("sslfactory", 
         "com.amazon.redshift.ssl.NonValidatingFactory");
        conn =DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:redshift://"+endpoint+":"+port+"/"+database, props);
       return conn;
     }catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.toString());
    }
    return conn;
}
```

And here are the maven dependencies:

```
    <dependency>
         <groupId>com.amazon.redshift</groupId>
        <artifactId>redshift-jdbc42-no-awssdk</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.10.1009</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.11.118</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-redshift</artifactId>
        <version>1.11.118</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-sts</artifactId>
        <version>1.11.118</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: What exception do you get when the connection drops?

Comment: Thats the exception i get : java.sql.SQLException: [Amazon](500150) Error setting/closing connection: Not Connected.

Comment: Please add the full exception stacktrace to your question

Comment: That's all i am getting back.

Comment: That is because you use `System.out.println(e.toString())`, use `e.printStackTrace()` instead

Answer (score 0):

Received exactly the same error message.

I looked into the [Redshift Events](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/working-with-events.html) and I noticed these 3 messages approximately at the same time of when I received the exception (5 mins delay probably):

- `Cluster 'my-cluster' began restart at 2019-01-23 15:56 UTC. We will attempt to park database connections for the duration of the restart.`
- `Amazon Redshift rebooted cluster my-cluster at 2019-01-23 15:56 UTC`
- `Cluster 'my-cluster' completed restart at 2019-01-23 15:57 UTC.`

I then looked at the CPU utilisation of the cluster and it was at 100% for several hours (indeed I was running 2 very resource consuming processes writing to Redshift). By looking into [this](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=251480) discussion in AWS Forums looks like that

> failure of these health checks normally occur due to high cluster load or intermittent networking errors

In my case the problem was a big workload which made the cluster unresponsive -> automatic reboot -> `java.sql.SQLException: [Amazon](500150) Error setting/closing connection: Not Connected.`